# How to create directory structure for php sessions?

Tags: php, session

In the php.ini file there is a note regarding the use of directory structures for session save path:

```
; NOTE 1: PHP will not create this directory structure automatically.
;         You can use the script in the ext/session dir for that purpose.
```

I searched and found this file which I believe is the script the notes are referring to:

```
/usr/include/php/20180731/ext/session/mod_files.h
```

But how do I "use" this script? It's not executable and the docs are short on details.

Comment: mod_files.h is just a C header file and not a script.  Not sure what it is referring to.

Comment: that makes (at least) two of us

Comment: The referred script is `mod_files.sh` (or `mod_files.bat` on Windows). https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path

Comment: @András - there is no such shell script on any of my servers.  Inside the etx/session directory are only `mod_files.h  mod_user.h  php_session.h`

Comment: Could you tell me which version of PHP do you use?

Comment: You can download mod_files.sh from PHP's git repo. https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/session/mod_files.sh

Answer (score 1):

If refers to [PHP source code](https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/session). You won't typically have it available on your server, unless you compiled PHP from sources.

From [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.save-path):

> A small shell script exists in ext/session to do this, it's called **mod_files.sh**, with a Windows version called **mod_files.bat**.

<del>The file you mention seems to be part of a third version written in C. You'd need to compile mod_files.c it with e.g. gcc.</del>        `mod_files.h` is a [C header file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html). It defines stuff to be used from *.c files. There's `mod_files.c` too. I don't know what they do.

Comment: Thanks, so do mod_files.c and mod_files.sh do the same thing?  Can I simply download mod_files.sh and run that one instead?

Comment: To be honest, I can't tell for sure. I'd just go for what's documented.

Comment: `mod_files.sh` and `mod_files.bat` do the same thing. The first is for Linux and the second for Windows. The file `mod_files.c` is the PHP source code for the `session.save handler` _files_.